# Is 'p' in 'trop' pronounced when followed by an adjective starting with vowel?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

In the following news (5 Mar) of RFI

> 60 % d'entre eux jugent que ces deux candidats sont **trop** âgés pour le poste de président des États-Unis.

the *p* is pronounced. I may simply have a false impression, but I've never heard *tro**p*** pronounced before.

Hence the question. Is *p* to be pronounced when followed by a vowel? For instance, should I pronounce *p* in *trop avancée*?

---

[This](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/liaisons-et-enchainements) does not seem to mention *p*.

Comment: I can't figure out how to link the particular episode, but the news site link is https://francaisfacile.rfi.fr/fr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is p to be pronounced when followed by a vowel?

It's always pronounced in poetry and it is common in formal speech. Otherwise the liaison is optional.

> For instance, should I pronounce p in *trop avancée*?

It's up to you. You'll be understood in either case.

Comment: Tiens, c'est une liaison que je ne fais pas toujours. De toute façon, ces liaisons, sont un peu volatiles. On les fait, on ne les fait pas...

Comment: @Frank Oui, *optional*!

Comment: In informal speech in Quebec, I think the p is almost never pronounced, and if it were, it would sound affected.

Comment: @Eggy Yes, In France too, the more casual the speech, the less we hear that liaison. The liaison seems to be rare in 'neutral' register too in Québec, although it can still appear like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp5Y_0IYOBU&t=2687s). 44'50": *trop à la légère*.

Comment: @jlliagre I admire how you find examples! I've watched that YouTube presenter before. One is immediately struck by his over-enuniciation. Do you agree?

Comment: @Eggy Oui, je dirais qu'il a une élocution très soignée, très affirmée.

Comment: Tropaffirmée, je dirais. :-)

Comment: @Eggy Tro-affirmée tu veux dire ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The rule is that the `p` should be pronounced. That being said, many native French speakers omit it when speaking at familiar level.

Said differently:

- for an interview where your French skills are tested, you should pronounce it
- for a *formal* discussion with a (potential) customer, you should pronounce it
- when speaking with friends, it is up to you